# Netlify fails build for React app - Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I am trying to deploy my React app to netlify. I did `npm run build` to make a production build. I tried to deploy to netlify via github and am getting this error.

Drag and Drop did not work, gets timed out

This is my file path
C:\Users\engineering\Documents\GitHub\mysite\client>

for build command I have tried:

```
npm start
npm run build
```

and someone recommended trying

```
CI= npm run build
```

none have work

For my publish directory I've tried

```
build/

client/
```

not sure how to fix this?

```
5:11:30 PM:   1. Build command from Netlify app                             
5:11:30 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:11:30 PM: ​
5:11:30 PM: $ npm run build
5:11:31 PM: npm ERR! Missing script: "build"
5:11:31 PM: npm ERR!
5:11:31 PM: npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
5:11:31 PM: npm ERR!   npm run
5:11:31 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
5:11:31 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-05-26T21_11_30_921Z-debug-0.log
5:11:31 PM: ​
5:11:31 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:11:31 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
5:11:31 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
5:11:31 PM: ​
5:11:31 PM:   Error message
5:11:31 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
5:11:31 PM: ​
5:11:31 PM:   Error location
5:11:31 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
5:11:31 PM:   npm run build
5:11:31 PM: ​
5:11:31 PM:   Resolved config
5:11:31 PM:   build:
5:11:31 PM:     command: npm run build
5:11:31 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
5:11:31 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
5:11:31 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
5:11:31 PM: Caching artifacts
```

when I use `client/` for the publish directory and `npm start` I get this and just sits here until it times out

```
5:38:22 PM: $ npm start
5:38:22 PM: > client@0.1.0 start
5:38:22 PM: > react-scripts start
5:38:24 PM: (node:1480) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
5:38:24 PM: (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
5:38:24 PM: (node:1480) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
5:38:24 PM: Starting the development server...
5:38:24 PM: 
5:38:37 PM: Compiled with warnings.
5:38:37 PM: 
5:38:37 PM: src/components/navbar/Navbar.jsx
5:38:37 PM:   Line 1:17:  'useRef' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars
5:38:37 PM:   Line 1:35:  'useEffect' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
5:38:37 PM: src/constants/images.js
5:38:37 PM:   Line 40:1:  Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export
5:38:37 PM: src/container/about/About.jsx
5:38:37 PM:   Line 2:18:  'useForceUpdate' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
5:38:37 PM: src/wrapper/AppWrap.js
5:38:37 PM:   Line 4:70:  Nested block is redundant  no-lone-blocks
5:38:37 PM: Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
5:38:37 PM: To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
5:38:37 PM: WARNING in src/components/navbar/Navbar.jsx
5:38:37 PM:   Line 1:17:  'useRef' is defined but never used     no-unused-vars
5:38:37 PM:   Line 1:35:  'useEffect' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
5:38:37 PM: src/constants/images.js
5:38:37 PM:   Line 40:1:  Assign object to a variable before exporting as module default  import/no-anonymous-default-export
5:38:37 PM: src/container/about/About.jsx
5:38:37 PM:   Line 2:18:  'useForceUpdate' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
5:38:37 PM: src/wrapper/AppWrap.js
5:38:37 PM:   Line 4:70:  Nested block is redundant  no-lone-blocks
5:38:37 PM: webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

Answer (score 1):

Netlify build will fail if you have warnings.

Comment: No need to add separate answer for this, you can simply add comment instead of spamming answer section.

Comment: How am I "spamming" the answer section when this is literally the answer to his problem ?